# How to get the View file for automatically generated SQL form using SQLFORM()?

Tags: python, web2py

The controller code generates the view automatically for the model file defining the database. How can I access the generated view file so that I can make necessary changes?

Comment: Please show your code and explain in more detail what you are seeing and what you want to change. I suspect you are referring to generic views, which attempt to render the dictionary returned by a controller action when you have not created an explicit view for the action. If you want to customize, you should not touch the generic view but instead create a custom view for the action. This is all covered in the documentation.

Comment: You're right. SQLFORM generates view automatically which can be changed by creating respective custom view file.

For example, if we type in controller
 "form = SQLFORM(db.person)"

I got the serialized view in the controller. 
I thought somewhere in view, there should be a file which contains the html form.  

Actually, I wished to get that generic view for my model in view file.

Comment: SQLFORM does not generate a view. Unfortunately, this doesn't clarify the situation. Please show your code if you would like further assistance. You might also consider posting on the web2py Google Group, which is more conducive to a back-and-forth discussion.